# Relative path is not accessing in html for an image after war file deployment in tomcat

Tags: html

Test project is deployed in Tomcat 7.0. Below are the directory structure of deployment project. 
We are facing the relative path issue in this Test project for an image.

```
 /webapps
   |--/Test
        |--/images
              |-- logo.jpg
        |--/META-INF
              |-- MANIFEST.MF
        |--/WEB-INF
              |-- /classes
              |-- /html
                    |--/index.html
              |--/lib
              |-- web.xml
```

below is my index.html page and web.xml file

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="../../images/logo.jpg"/>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/html/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

When we try to access http://localhost:8080/Test/ then logo.jpg is not loaded. 
Relative path is not accessing in index.html after deployment in tomcat 7.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<img src="images/logo.jpg"/>
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it's better to explain why your code should work. What did you change, why? How does your path work? Etc.

Comment: @Wouter, thanks your suggestion, I just wanted to say that all paths are with reference to WEB_INF, thus we should not try to specify the relative path with reference to the location of our jsp/html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving a related path, best practice is to use absolute dynamic path starting from your context.

As below:

```
<img src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/images/logo.jpg" />
```

Or better in jstl using `${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}`

```
<img src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/images/logo.jpg" />
```

It will always help you irrespective of your directory structure.

Comment: Hi Parth,  we can not use scriplet and el syntex in html. Please provide some other solution.

Comment: Hi @AnujVerma, As question was tagged as `java`, i believe you're using `jsp`. I think it's better to make it as `jsp`. Why are you using `html`?

Comment: I am facing this issue with spring with angular js project and we only used html in project so i asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
${pageContext.request.contextPath}
```

this will return your current context path and hence you can access anywhere from here.

Comment: we can not use ${pageContext.request.contextPath} in html. Please provide some other solution.

Comment: as it is related to java, so i think you used jsp instead of html. if you used jsp then it would be better.